# search does not work from "Causer by" in laravel

Tags: laravel

Search doesn't work beacuse relationship isn't ok

```
public function causer($causer)
{
    $user = User::where('email', 'LIKE', "%$causer%")->first();
    return $user ? $this->builder->causedBy($user) : null;
}
```

Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: welcome to SO. What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think thats because `$this->builder` is instance of database query builder, you could try

```
return $user ? self::causedBy($user) : null;
```